# Any other GraphQL Federation implementations apart from Apollo?

Tags: graphql, federation, apollo-federation

I have been trying to build a federation gateway on top of existing graphql services and am curious if there are any other implementations of the same apart from apollo federation?

I tried to find but couldn't find any. I am also looking for subscription on the federated gateway. Does anybody know any other implementations on the same?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [fastify-gql](https://github.com/mcollina/fastify-gql) now supports being a Federation Gateway, with subscription support included.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

0. Graphene (for python) with Graphene-Federation implements federation (there  is in built support for graphql subscriptions). I have used this for a large-scale project and it works just fine (Although I personally prefer apollo)
1. I haven't personally used this, but tyk.io seems to have a pretty neat solution for federation: https://tyk.io/blog/an-introduction-to-graphql-federation/
2. Bramble - https://movio.co/blog/building-a-new-api-platform-for-movio/
   Great for GoLang. I haven't used it, but I have a friend who has

Something else that is not pure "federation" per-se - but which would solve your problem easily is GraphQL Mesh. https://www.graphql-mesh.com/

Hope this helps :) !